# Rotate Bitmap Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, bitmap, rotation, xamarin.android

I am loading an image from a webserver, I want to rotate it if the orientation is wrong. I've seen how to do it from a bitmap on my phone, it takes the filename but nothing with an actual bitmap. I am using this to resize it, but unsure on the rotate part.

```
public Bitmap resizeAndRotate(Bitmap image, int width, int height)
{
    Bitmap newImage= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, newWidth, newHeight, true);
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can scale and rotate the bitmap in one call by passing a `Android.Graphics.Matrix` that include both the scale and rotation in the transformation to `Bitmap.CreateBitmap`:

```
public Bitmap resizeAndRotate(Bitmap image, int width, int height)
{
    var matrix = new Matrix();
    var scaleWidth = ((float)width) / image.Width;
    var scaleHeight = ((float)height) / image.Height;
    matrix.PostRotate(90);
    matrix.PreScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    return Bitmap.CreateBitmap(image, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, matrix, true);
}
```

Comment: will that rotate it only if it needs rotating? not all need it.

Comment: @LarrySeymour What do you mean "needs" rotating? The example code `.PostRotate(90);` will always rotate the bitmap, if the original image has `Exif` data, you can conditional skip this matrix rotation and only scale the the image.

Comment: with my app i can take a photo, buy defauilt it is in landscape. if i take it in portrait it still saves it in landscape, so not all photosd need rotating. initially i can rotate using exif if my photo is still on the phone, but i save the images top my web server then dopwnload them as needed.  when using exif i padss the filename into a size and rotate method, but when recalling from the ewerbserver i dont have that filename string to use.  how can i gety the exif data from a Bitmap that is passed in tp my method?

Comment: @LarrySeymour If the image is not preserving the Exif metadata, or you do not have access it that original data (via embedding it in a database, the image filename, etc..) then you will not know whether to rotate it or not.... the actual bitmap data (RGBA) has no knowledge of up/left/rotation...

Comment: @SushiHangover Any idea how I can do this for Xamarin.ios?